# Why my laravel App is always in production mood

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

When I try to run command like -

```
php artisan db:seed
```

it is saying -

```
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

 Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
```

My .env file says -

```
....
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=...
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost
....
```

my app.php file says

```
...
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'local'),
...
```

My laravel version is 5.3.

What setting should I do to run the application in development mode?

Comment: On the command line, what does `echo $APP_ENV` (or `echo %APP_ENV%` on Windows) show?

Comment: using windows. echo %APP_ENV% returns back   %APP_ENV%.   when  I run "php artisan env" it returns back "Current application environment: production"

Answer (score 2):

Your settings are correct. Try to clear config cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Still the problem exists. I am using netbeans in windows 10 environment. Restarted apache server after running the command too. :(

Comment: How about remove this file: `bootstrap/cache/config.php` manually from file explorer?

Comment: There is no config.php in bootstrap/cache folder in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the command on the terminal or cmd

```
php artisan up
```

it will come you out of the maintenance mode

Comment: Then might be some error in your env file please post your env file that might help